# Ininit loop occuring while I update ref in React Select when I want to check all boxes

Tags: reactjs, react-select, ref

I am working on a Select field. I am using react-select library. I have added Ref and i want to check all options, i use the setValue() on the Ref but this leads to an infinite re rendering

I tried putting the ref call in useEffect hook but still it re-render

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `import { useRef } from 'react';
import Select, { components } from 'react-select';
export const  MySelect = () => {
const selectInputRef = useRef();
if(selectInputRef.current.getValue().map((val)=>if(val=="All"){selectInputRef.setValue([]))
return(
<div>
        <Select
          closeMenuOnSelect={false}
          isMulti
          options={options}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        ref={selectInputRefField}
          value={values}
          components={{ MultiValue }}
        />
      </div>
)
}`